# FastApi (Starlette) + NGINX Proxy: URL scheme in Request Object not correct?

Tags: nginx, https, fastapi, reverse-proxy, starlette

I'd like to know the following

- How does Starlette set the "url" property in the Request object - especially when operated behind a NGINX proxy.
- How can `request.url` be manipulated on the NGINX level  -- setting proxy headers doesn't modify it at all?
- How can `request.url` be manipulated via a Starlette Middleware -- somehow what I did doesn't have any effect?

The setting is like this:

I have a FastAPI app running behind a NGINX proxy. Via the browser, I send requests to NGINX via HTTPS (`https://www.example.com`) , but whatever I do, `request.url` on Starlette's side is always `http://www.example.com`.

I made a small FastAPI endpoint for demonstration purposes

```py
@app.get("/test")
def some_test(request: Request):
    return {"request.url": request.url,
            "request['headers']": request["headers"],
            "request.client": request.client}
```

and in the following screenshots I show what I get (domain is anonymized; set to `xyz`):
[image]

1. I call in the browser `https://www.example.com/test`
2. In the console, I see that properly the request is issues to `https://www.example.com/test`
3. But when looking at Starlette's `Request.url`, it says `http://www.example.com/test`

Is this behaviour how it should be? In the screenshot I also print the `host` and `x-forwarded-proto` and `x-forwarded-schema` which I set the NGINX config to HTTPS, but the object `Request` isn't modified at all by that.

What can I do to correct this on the NGINX or FastAPI/Starlette level?

- I already tried setting various commands like

  ```
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
  ```

  with no success at all.
- I tried to write a custom Starlette Middleware (I know that's quite ugly, but I wanted to try this out to better understand, what's going on)

  ```py
  from fastapi import Request
  from starlette.datastructures import URL

  @app.middleware("http")
  async def some_middlware(request: Request, call_next):

      if "/test" in str(request.url):
          print(f"before {request.url}")
          request._url = URL(str(request.url).replace("http", "https"))
          print(f"after {request.url}")

      response = await call_next(request)
      return response
  ```

  but this also doesn't modify the `request.url` shown in the response.

Comment: How are you running Starlette? With `uvicorn`? In that case, uvicorn has `--proxy-headers` to provide request metadata from the expected proxy headers: https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-from-the-command-line - in particular, see the section [about "Running behind nginx"](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-behind-nginx).

Comment: @MatsLindh

Now it works!

I already started uvicorn with `--proxy-headers` and  --forwarded-allow-ips. But my problem was, that I used the parameter for the allowed IPs incorrectly.

This doesn't work: `uvicorn --proxy-headers  --forwarded-allow-ips='*'`.
This works instead: `uvicorn --proxy-headers  --forwarded-allow-ips=*`. (Note the quotation marks)

To be precises, as i'm using it in a Dockerfile, my entrypoint looks like


`ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--proxy-headers", "--forwarded-allow-ips=*", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the proxying of the schema works.

The problem was,the following:

Before my Dockerfile looked like

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--proxy-headers", "--forwarded-allow-ips='*'", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

The quotation marks in the `--forwarded-allow-ips` parameter do not work. Instead the entrypoint should read

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--proxy-headers", "--forwarded-allow-ips=*", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Hint: To be a bit cleaner, one should not allow `*` as an IP address, instead you should specify the IP address.